# pythonを使った画像内の物体認識

Tags: python, python3, windows, opencv, 画像

Python（WinPython3）とOpenCVを使って画像処理プログラミングを行っています。

デジカメ等で撮影された画像において、画像に写った建物などを認識させるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

具体的には、青空を背景に建物がいくつか並んでいる場合、空に重なる全ての構造物をオブジェとして認識させたいです。そして、グラフを画像上に重ねた場合に、グラフと建物との交点が取り出せるようにしたいと思っています。

画像処理に関して詳しい方がいれば、手順や方法をわかりやすく教えてほしいです。よろしくお願いします。
（画像の赤丸が認識した点）

[image: 赤丸が認識した点]

Answer (score 1):

公式にあるcascade

> https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

公式には建物のcascade_fileがないようなので他で探すか自分で作ってから
[ここ](https://www.superdatascience.com/opencv-face-recognition/)と同じ作業をすればひとまずビルを認識することは可能かと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。とりあえずまずは公式にあるcascade "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"を使って顔認識をさせようとしたのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てきてしまいます。このエラーの意味は何なのでしょうか？また、このエラーの原因は何なのか教えてほしいです。                               
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

Comment: 上記コメントについての質問が https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47419/python%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE%E9%A1%94%E6%A4%9C%E5%87%BA で行われています。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale

ここに回答があります。おそらくパスが違うのでしょう