# pythonを使った画像上の顔検出

Tags: python, python3, windows, opencv, 画像

以下のコードで画像の顔認識をおこないたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
（カスケードの参照元：https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades ）

```
import cv2

def main():

  　# 入力画像の読み込み
  　img = cv2.imread("JPG画像")

  　# カスケード型識別器の読み込み
  　cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

  　# グレースケール変換
  　gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  　# 顔領域の探索
  　face = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(30, 30))

    # 顔領域を赤色の矩形で囲む
　  for (x, y, w, h) in face:
      　cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y+h), (0,0,200), 3)

  　# 結果を出力
  　cv2.imshow("result.jpg",img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

> error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

このエラーの出る原因がわかりません。どなたか解決策を教えてください。

Comment: この方法で建物の検出も行いたいので、建物のカスケードファイルの在り処もしくは作り方について知っている方がいれば、それも合わせて教えていただきたいです。

Comment: [error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale) によれば、`haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` のパス指定に問題がありそうですね。

Comment: カスケードファイルがある場所をちゃんと指定しているのですが、エラーが直りません。カスケードファイルの保存先が関係していたりしますか？その場合どこに保存しておくのがいいでしょうか？